# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

[Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Thread')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiiM0.png)

This error is persistent even though I'm connected to the DB.

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const threadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: true,
    },
    community: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Community",
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
    parentId: {
        type: String,
    },
    children: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Thread",
        },
    ],
});

const Thread = mongoose.models.Thread || mongoose.model("Thread", threadSchema);

export default Thread;
```

I tried this connecting before this but go the same result.

```js
    let thread = null;
    try {
        thread = await fetchThreadById(params.id);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching thread:", error);
        return null; // Handle the error appropriately
    }

    if (!thread) {
        return null; // Handle the case where thread is not found
    }
```